# Adding Facebook Pop in swift project (iOS 8.0 target) through cocoapods impossible

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to add FB's famous animation framework 'Pop' to my project using Cocoapods.

The process seems straight-forward to me, but somehow I am getting an linker error:

My process of installing Pop through CocoaPods is the following:

-I go to my root project folder in the terminal and I execute `pod init`. This creates my `Podfile`

-I open my `Podfile` and I add `pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'` :

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

target 'Test' do
pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
end

target 'TestTests' do

end
```

-Then, I execute `pod install`, which adds CocoaPods in my project.

-I get this info in my terminal:

```
[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Test.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
```

-I open that file instead of my regular project, and I get a bunch of errors & warnings:

[image: Errors1]

[image]

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? Am I skipping something in the procedure?

Also, I am getting a red file (I guess it is not finding the correct file) under Frameworks in my Test project in Xcode:

[image]

I think it would be easier to install it manually, but I have no idea how to do it. If anyone knows how to do it, I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide regarding this matter, if not, installing it correctly through cocoapods it's fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your podfile, add following line:

```
inhibit_all_warnings! # this will disable all the warnings for all pods
```

Then run pod install again, which will remove all the warning connected with pods from your build (no need to worry about them).

As for the red ones, it seems that those are not connected to POP framework but to Facebook SDK (which is AFAIK not required for POP to work). Are you sure you are not missing some other libraries that you forgot to add to you pod file?

Comment: To make this easier, I just created a blank project and installed cocoapods there. I added that line after the comments and it seems to compile. Do you know how I can use the framework? Do I need to use a header file?

Comment: You need to use bridging header (if you don't already have it, follow this tutorial: https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/). Then, add #import "POP.h" to that bridging header. Then you can use pop everywhere in your app.

Comment: I did have a bridging header already. I kind of got it working. Now I can see  only methods, such as pop_addAnimation  and pop_addAnimationForKey... but whenever I try to create an object from a POP class, such as POPBasicAnimation -> `var animation:POPBasicAnimation = POPBasicAnimation()` it says `Use of undeclared type 'POPBasicAnimation'` ... so therefore I am not getting the class files? I guess??